# Open local html file from current html file Android Studio?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-webview

I made a WebView app on Android Studio.
It opens my default index HTML page correctly

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kurven_untersucher);
    WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
}
```

till now it's good. Now I made a link in my HTML page to open another HTML file in my local directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="test.html">test</a>
</body>
```

but when I install the APK on my android phone, it crashes after clicking on that link.

how can I solve this?

Here is the logcat error

```
08-18 12:51:22.798 22903-22903/com.thejami.kurvenuntersucher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thejami.kurvenuntersucher, PID: 22903
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/www/test.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10511)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:757)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:744)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:377)
    at ahj.startActivity(SourceFile:22)
    at aeV.a(SourceFile:28)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(SourceFile:173)
    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SourceFile:9)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: enter logcat here

Comment: `open another HTML file in my local directory` ?? Where would that be? Your index.html comes from a subdirectory of assets.

Comment: @EmdadHossain nothing showed up in the logcat

Comment: @greenapps the second file is also added in the /www/ directory, but it still doesn't open. the html file load all images and js from the directory but doesn't open any other html files

Comment: It does not open ? Or does it crash?

Comment: @greenapps when I click on that link, I get a message "App has stopped." and everything gets closed

Comment: @EmdadHossain nvm, now I got some errors in the logcat. check my original post

Comment: @greenapps I added the logcat in my original post, after the app crashes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: A FileUriExposedException for a file in assets. Unbelievable! Which Android version?

Comment: @greenapps yes test.html shall be filetwo.html just other names

Comment: @greenapps done

Answer (score 1):

you can use from below code:

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webview is not going to display file test.html. Instead the webview creates an intent to let the user choose an external browser. Then you get a FileUriExposedException.

If you want to load the file in the webview itself you should let schouldOverrideUrlLoading return true or false.

Or something like that.

Comment: how am I supposed to do that :)

Comment: You override that memberfunction (of the webclient i think). A little googling should give examples.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
 WebView lWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
 File lFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + " 
 <FOLDER_PATH_TO_FILE>/<FILE_NAME>");
 lWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + lFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Where should I add this? srry but I'm new in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this below the webView codes, solved the problem

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
        }
});
```